# SQL request - SELECT with multiple empty values

Tags: java, mysql, sql, select, request

I have a database with multiple columns. Now i have a Java program where i can search for different rows in my database. But i need help for the SQL SELECT request. 
I have some texfields and some checkboxes. Now i want if the textfields are empty, or "any" is selected in one of the checkboxes , the select request should select ALL from this column.

Here is my request right now:

```
resultSet = sqlStatement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Messgerate WHERE COLUMN1 LIKE '%"+sColumn1+"%'" +
"AND COLUMN2 LIKE '%"+sColumn2+"%'" +
"AND COLUMN3 LIKE '%"+sColumn3+"%'" +
"AND COLUMN4 LIKE '%"+sColumn4+"%'" +
"AND COLUMN5 LIKE '%"+sColumn5+"%'" +
"AND COLUMN6 LIKE '%"+sColumn6+"%'" +"");
```

This request ist working if i type in something in all of the textfields and checkboxes.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: You really should read up on proper use of `PreparedStatement`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you replace `AND` with `OR`. It ll solve your issue. Because the `AND` operator displays a record if both the first condition AND the second condition are true.

The `OR` operator displays a record if either the first condition OR the second condition is true.

```
"SELECT * FROM Messgerate WHERE COLUMN1 LIKE '%"+sColumn1+"%'" +
"OR COLUMN2 LIKE '%"+sColumn2+"%'"
"OR COLUMN3 LIKE '%"+sColumn3+"%'" +
"OR COLUMN4 LIKE '%"+sColumn4+"%'" +
"OR COLUMN5 LIKE '%"+sColumn5+"%'" +
"OR COLUMN6 LIKE '%"+sColumn6+"%'" +"");
```

Comment: but if i use OR , just one of all statements must me true , right? but i want all statements must be true

Comment: Yes, if you want all statements must be true, use AND and check Which checkboxes are selected and pass those values

Comment: If AND, all the column should be matched

Comment: is there no easier way? Because the code will be huge if i have to write so many requests

Comment: `You want if the textfields are empty, or "any" is selected in one of the checkboxes`. Just check it

Comment: Awww my bad! it works with AND when i set the strings empty if "any" is selected! Thanks Alot

Answer (score 0):

You should pass an empty string when `Any` is selected in the dropdown. And then you can use this:

```
resultSet = sqlStatement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Messgerate WHERE COLUMN1 LIKE '%"+sColumn1+"%'" +
"OR COLUMN2 LIKE '%"+sColumn2+"%'" +
"OR COLUMN3 LIKE '%"+sColumn3+"%'" +
"OR COLUMN4 LIKE '%"+sColumn4+"%'" +
"OR COLUMN5 LIKE '%"+sColumn5+"%'" +
"OR COLUMN6 LIKE '%"+sColumn6+"%'" +"");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from messgerate where case when isnull(sColumn1,'') = '' then '' when isnull(sColumn1,'') = 'any' then '' else COLUMN1 end LIKE '%"+sColumn1+"%'"
```

Repeat the case statement for the rest of the columns